# SLF4J : simplelogger.properties in the project not detected

Tags: scala, log4j, sbt, slf4j, spark-submit

I am using `Grizzled-SLF4J` (a wrapper around `SLF4J`) for my `Spark`/`Scala`/`SBT` Project. The property file `simplelogger.properties` has been placed in the `src/main/resources`. But the `property file` is not getting detected when I run the Application using `spark-submit`. Whatever the change I make to `property file` is not getting reflected and seems like some `default` values for the properties are used(In my case only `WARN` / `ERROR` messages are displayed).

Here is my **build.sbt**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "myprojectname",
    ...,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-slf4j" % "1.3.0",
     "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.22",
     "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.22",
    )
 )
```

**simplelogger.properties**

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile         = System.err
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel = debug
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime    = false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat  = yyyy'/'MM'/'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss'-'S
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName  = true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName     = true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showShortLogName= false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.levelInBrackets = true
```

Am I missing something here?

PS : I did checked the `Jar` and `simplelogger.properties` is available in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it to the root, add it under `resources`, next to `scala` code folder:

```
/
  src
  main
    resources
      simplelogger.properties
    scala
```

Obviously this is not only valid for `simplelogger.properties` but for any other kind of file that you want in the classpath at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle until I tried to set the properties manually using `System.setProperty(org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel,"DEBUG");`
and I noticed that these properties were not present in the slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar

Make sure to get at least `slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar` . The prior versions don't support properties

> org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile

or

> org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel

Upgrading to 1.7.25 picked up the simple logger config from simplelogger.properties